# Component-wise boolean operations and indexing with nalgebra

Tags: rust, nalgebra

As an example for what I'm trying to replicate in Rust with nalgebra, consider the following Python code using NumPy:

```py
import numpy as np

value = np.array([1.0, 2.0, 3.0])
error = np.array([0.01, 0.01, 0.01])

current_value = np.array([2.0, 3.0, 4.0])
current_error = np.array([0.1, 0.001, 0.001])
    
improved = current_error < error
value[improved] = current_value[improved]
error[improved] = current_error[improved]

print(error)
print(value)
```

Two vectors of errors are compared to each other. Then, for any components where the error decreased, the previous `error` and `value` is replaced with the current one. It is done by a component-wise boolean operation that produces the intermiediate vector `improved`, which can then be used to index the other vectors.

This kind of indexing doesn't seem to be possible with `nalgebra`, so I currently only have this basic loop solution:

```rust
use nalgebra::{dvector};

fn main() {
    let mut value = dvector![1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
    let mut error = dvector![0.01, 0.01, 0.01];

    let current_value = dvector![2.0, 3.0, 4.0];
    let current_error = dvector![0.1, 0.001, 0.001];
    
    for i in 0..error.len() {
        if current_error[i] < error[i] {
            value[i] = current_value[i];
            error[i] = current_error[i];
        }
    }

    println!("{}", error);
    println!("{}", value);
}
```

It works fine, but I wonder if there are there more elegant ways to achieve this? Any iterator/zip contraption I tried ended up way too complicated.

Comment: The Rust version is two lines longer and avoids allocating an intermediate array… seems worth it.

Comment: @BallpointBen The Rust version may be slower because the loop may not be vectorized.

Comment: Vectorization isn't parallelization, it just means your `for` loops are in C instead of Python. It's possible to get parallelization for these kinds of vector ops (with `numba` or `numexpr` or whatever) but it's not what numpy does by default. Furthermore I wouldn't be surprised if Rust SIMD-ifies this loop just in the ordinary course of optimization.